# Firebase suddenly stopped

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have recently implemented admob in my app, and until today morning, it was working properly.
Unfortunately, I had deleted my app in firebase today morning, and then I re-created the project, and added the new `google-service.json`.

But, I have neither received a new mail as the service is enabled (I havn't receive the deletion either) nor I am getting any ad with real id. 
This is the bottom of the log.

```
 D/FA: Connected to remote service
 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=app_clear_data(_cd),params=Bundle[{}]
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2712159
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Unscheduling upload
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload, millis: 2712159
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 103
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=5481837217645203518}]
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2711692
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Unscheduling upload
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload, millis: 2711692
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 391
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=am,name=ad_query(_aq),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=am, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=5481837217645203518, ad_event_id(_aeid)=5481837217645203519}]
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2711093
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Unscheduling upload
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload, millis: 2711093
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 183
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=am,name=ad_query(_aq),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=am, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=5481837217645203518, ad_event_id(_aeid)=5481837217645203520}]
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2710954
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Unscheduling upload
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload, millis: 2710954
 2667-15043/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 146
 14794-14847/com.example.phocast V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: so your issue is about AdMob?

Comment: Probably its firebase, as I am getting the test ads from admob, if I use test ids

Comment: If you firebase console is saying you app is connected, trust it ;) admob can take hours to start serving ads. anyway double check your app on admob console